# How to send live location of the device android [ duplicate]

Tags: android, kotlin, location, background-process

Problem Statement:-
In my application, the background service worked,  I sent the user's GPS location, and current location from the provider. But I want to share the live location what is the right approach for sending a live location in the background?

What should I use firebase, live server APIs, or any other platform?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Firebase live database. But I have implemented API to send location data on every location update.

Answer (score 0):

This class will help you for sending live location updates in the background:

import class :

```
import android.Manifest
import android.content.Context
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.location.Location
import android.location.LocationListener
import android.location.LocationManager
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle
import androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleObserver
import androidx.lifecycle.OnLifecycleEvent
import androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleOwner
```

and this the LocationTracker class :

class LocationTracker(private val context: Context) : LocationListener, LifecycleObserver {

```
private var locationManager: LocationManager? = null

@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
fun startLocationUpdates() {
    if (checkLocationPermission()) {
        locationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
        locationManager?.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10000, 0f, this)
    }
}

@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
fun stopLocationUpdates() {
    locationManager?.removeUpdates(this)
}

override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location) {
    // Send location updates to server here
    val latitude = location.latitude
    val longitude = location.longitude
    // Your code to send location data to the server
}

override fun onStatusChanged(provider: String?, status: Int, extras: Bundle?) {
    // Unused callback
}

override fun onProviderEnabled(provider: String?) {
    // Unused callback
}

override fun onProviderDisabled(provider: String?) {
    // Unused callback
}

private fun checkLocationPermission(): Boolean {
    val permission = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
    val result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission)
    return result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
}}
```

Example usage

```
// Create an instance of LocationTracker in your activity or fragment
val locationTracker = LocationTracker(context)

// Register the location tracker to start receiving updates when the app 
// is in the foreground
ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().lifecycle.addObserver(locationTracker)

// Unregister the location tracker when it's no longer needed
ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().lifecycle.removeObserver(locationTracker)
```